# getStaticProps Next JS Doesn't Work in Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I make getStaticProps in pages, in local it's work but in production doesn't work. my code is below:

```
import {GetStaticProps} from 'next';
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await apiAboutV2();
  const data = res ?? {};

  return {
    props: {about: _.result(data, 'data', {})},
    revalidate: true,
  };
};

interface Props {
  about: any;
}

export default function About({about}: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
{about?.history}
</div>
)
}
```

anyone can suggestion for me?

edit:

```
export const apiAboutV2 = async () => {
  const uri = `${baseUrl}/api/v2/public/about`;
  const res = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: uri,
  })
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((err) => err?.response?.data || err);

  return res;
};
```

code above is apiAboutV2

Comment: What does "doesn't work"mean? Do you get a bad response? Do you get an error? Provide more details.

Comment: no error, the response is undefined @lawrence-witt

Comment: Are you certain it's not erroring? If you add a `console.log(err)` inside the `axios` catch, do you see anything in the server logs? It could be your `baseUrl` isn't properly setup in production.

Comment: yes not any error, I try api inside the function not getstaticprops the result data display @juliomalves

Comment: Is `/api/v2/public/about` a Next.js API route, or an external API?

Comment: that's external api @juliomalves